# Prove quadratic inequality is greater

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to show that

$4x^2 - 2xy + (5/2)y^2 \geq 0$.

Intuitively, this makes sense, but I don't know how to go about proving it.

Comment: I don't see why this should be intuitive (unless you already know how to do it). However you can argue that this is $\ge 0$ for $y=0$ while, if $y\ne 0$, you can divide both sides by the positive quantity $y^2$ and obtain a polynomial inequation in the variable $t=\frac xy$.

Comment: Surely $4x^2 - 2xy + (5/2)y^2 \geq x^2-2xy+y^2 = (x-y)^2 \geq 0$ works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, multiply it by $2$, then you get: $$8x^2 -4xy+5y^2\geq 0$$

rewrite as $$4x^2+(4x^2-4xy+y^2)+4y^2\geq 0$$

which is the same as $$4x^2+(2x-y)^2+4y^2\geq 0$$ which is obviously true.

Comment: By the trivial inequality

Answer (score 1):

$3x^2+x^2-2xy +y^2+(3/2)y^2=$

$3x^2 +(x-y)^2 + (3/2)y^2 \ge 0;$

All of the above terms are $\ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem, you should try to complete the square. You want to write your equation in the form $$[f(x,y)]^2+cy^2$$
If $c>0$, then your inequality is proved. $$4x^2-2xy+\frac 52 y^2=4x^2-2xy+\frac14 y^2-\frac14 y^2+\frac 52 y^2=(2x-\frac 12 y)^2+\frac 94 y^2$$

Answer (score 0):

If $y=0$ then inequality is correct. If $y>0$ then use $t = \frac{x}{y}$

$$4x^2 - 2xy + (5/2)y^2 \geq 0$$ divide $y^2$ and replace by $t$

$$4t^2 - 2t + (5/2) \geq 0$$

$\Delta= -6$ therefore no real roots. put $t=0$ and it is all positive.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant  of $4x^2 - 2xy + (5/2)y^2 $ equals $D=-36 y^2 \leq 0$.
 Thus $4x^2 - 2xy + (5/2)y^2 \geq 0$  for all $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way, using AM-GM inequality,
$$4x^2+\frac52y^2 \geqslant 2\sqrt{10}\;|xy| \geqslant 2xy$$